# libldap.so: undefined reference to

Tags: reference, hyperlink, uwsgi

Got the following linking problem when pip installing uWSGI in a virtualenv, am I missing some packages?

*** uWSGI linking ***

```
gcc -pthread -o /srv/www/ldap/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o lib/linux_ns.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/ldap.o core/ssl.o core/legion.o proto/zeromq.o core/xmlconf.o core/sqlite3.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/pyth/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_write@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memvfree_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_sb_copy_out@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memfree_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_free@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_log_dump@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_sb_buf_init@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_socket_set_nonblock@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_bvreplace@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_bvfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_next_element@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_add_io@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_ctrl@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_bvarray_free@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_skip_data@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_skip_tag@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_first_element@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_bvecfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_strdup_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_get_stringbv@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_alloc_t@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_io_debug@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_dup@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_io_udp@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_init@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_set_option@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_sb_do_write@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_log_print@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_flatten2@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_sb_grow_buffer@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_read@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_log_printf@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_get_int@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_free@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_pvt_sb_buf_destroy@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_str2bv@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_int_sb_close@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_get_next@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_get_option@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_scanf@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_rewind@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_io_tcp@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_ptrlen@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_dupbv@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_flatten@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_printf@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_strndup_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_strdup@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memcalloc@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_reset@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_remove_io@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_io_fd@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memcalloc_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memrealloc@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_init2@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_int_sb_read@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memrealloc_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memvfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memalloc@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_decode_oid@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_memalloc_x@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_flush2@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_peek_tag@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_io_readahead@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_alloc@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so: undefined reference to `ber_get_enum@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by libldap.so which installed by liblidap2-dev in order to compile openldap server.

Once I removed that package uwsgi started to compile fine again.